# Unexpected behavior with ungetc()

Tags: c

I fed to *stdin* "11+3" with the following code, and

```
void main(void) {
    int number;
    printf("the first call : %d\n", scanf("%d", &number));
    char ch = fgetc(stdin);
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    printf("the second call : %d\n", scanf("%d", &number));
}
```

the results seemed strange to me **because the second *scanf()* should have failed**. FYI, I used gcc 5.4.0 20160609 under Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4.

```
the first call : 1
the second call : 1
```

Comment: Why should it have failed? +3 is a valid number for scanf to parse.

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't expect that. What if there is a white space between '+' and numbers? Should the second call still work?

Comment: Sorry. Then it should fail, yes. scanf reads whitesapce delimited input. So the + and 3 are now separate "tokens".

Comment: No, [it doesn't](http://ideone.com/fDwvpN)

Comment: Thank you guys. Have a nice day~~~~~!

Answer (score 1):

> because the second scanf() should have failed.

No. You fed perfectly valid input to it.

scanf parses input until the input is satisfied or until it hits a delimiter.

In your first call to scanf, it parses "11" as number 11, and then concludes since the next digit isn't part of a number that the input is satisfied.

In your second call to scanf, it parses "+3" as number 3, which is a valid expression of positive 3 in integer form. Just as "-3" would have been for negative number 3.

As mentioned in the comments though, passing "11+ 3" would cause the second scanf to fail, since it'd try to parse "+" as an integer (the whitespace after the + is counted as a delimiter).